# how to place circular image-view on layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

But i ended up creating something like this :

[image]

How do i get circular edge to the imageview ? Note that layout containing text have overlapped imageview as well.

Here is my layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/accent_white"
            android:id="@+id/vendoravatar_imageview"
            android:src="@drawable/avatarnotfound" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/data_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </View>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/accent_white"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/random_vendoruser1"
                    android:id="@+id/vendorusername_textview"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:text="@string/random_vendoruser1"
                    android:id="@+id/vendoruserdesc_textview"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/editvuser_imageview"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pencil"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:background="@color/client_grey"
                        ></View>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/deletevuser_imageciew"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dustbin_color"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:background="@color/client_grey"
                        ></View>
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/lockvuser_imageview"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lock_open_24dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help, thanks in advance. I'm just addings some text to avoid mostly code error from stackoverflow.

Comment: use normal `ImageView` (not any custom `CircleImageView`) with `android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable`

Comment: I think your `avatarnotfound` image is not transparent

Comment: Your image should grow and shrink depending on the screen size. Try using ConstraintLayout to achieve your goal.

Comment: Just remove `android:background="@color/accent_white"` from your `CircleImageView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  Remove **`android:background="@color/accent_white"`** from your **`CircleImageView`**

```
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/vendoravatar_imageview"
            android:src="@drawable/nilesh" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/data_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </View>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="accent_white"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="random_vendoruser1"
                    android:id="@+id/vendorusername_textview"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:text="random_vendoruser1"
                    android:id="@+id/vendoruserdesc_textview"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/editvuser_imageview"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/deletevuser_imageciew"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/lockvuser_imageview"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/vendoravatar_imageview"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/data_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="accent_white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vendorusername_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="random_vendoruser1"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vendoruserdesc_textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="random_vendoruser1"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/editvuser_imageview"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/deletevuser_imageciew"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/lockvuser_imageview"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/vendoravatar_imageview"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nilesh" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @Downvoters Please explain exactly what's wrong with this answer so that I can address?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't help. That gives the look of circular imageview and a white linear layout with white background to its right. Agenda is to have a bigger circular image and a smaller layout which looks like the extension of same imageview. Take a closer look at what im trying to achieve.

Comment: what does `android:background` have to do with the original issue?

Comment: @pskink check the output when added `android:background` in `CircleImageView` https://i.stack.imgur.com/t63u9.png

Comment: @SumukhaAithalK We all are here to Just give you example and solve your error and not to create a exact view .

Comment: I haven't downvoted anything here. Please don't get the wrong idea. I'm just looking for help and his answer didn't serve my purpose and i left it there.

Comment: @SumukhaAithalK Hope his edited answer serve your purpose :)

Comment: No it doesn't. @FaizMir I'm sorry to say, you are not exactly helping me in any way. Can you please give any valuable input or stay out of this question altogether ?

Answer (score 0):

> To make a circular ImageView add CircularImageView in your layout XML
>   and add CircularImageView library in your project or you can also grab
>   it via Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
```

> and then use this in xml where you want that circular image

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        app:civ_shadow_color="#8BC34A"/>
```